# how to get just a string from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to define a function with two arguments : df (dataframe), and an integer (employerID) as my arguments. this function will return the full name of the employer.

If the given ID does not belong to any employee, I want to return the string "UNKNOWN" / If no middle name is given only return "LAST, FIRST". / If only the middle initial is given the return the full name in the format "LAST, FIRST M." with the middle initial followed by a '.'.

```
def getFullName(df, int1):
    df = pd.read_excel('/home/data/AdventureWorks/Employees.xls')
    newdf = df[(df['EmployeeID'] == int1)]
    print("'" + newdf['LastName'].item() + "," + " " + newdf['FirstName'].item() + " " + newdf['MiddleName'].item() + "." + "'")

getFullName('df', 110)
```

I wrote this code but came up with two problems :
1) if I don't put quotation mark around df, it will give me an error message, but I just want to take a data frame as an argument not a string.

2) this code can't deal with someone with out middle name.

I am sorry but I used pd.read_excel to read the excel file which you can not access. I know it will be hard for you to test the codes without the excel file, if someone let me know how to create a random data frame with the column names, I will go ahead and change it. Thank you,

Comment: Some sample data in text form would be useful.

Comment: What error are you getting?  The error message would also be helpful.

Comment: error message saying "name 'df' is not defined" if I do not put quotation around df. 

also, employeeID (259, 278, 204). FirstName(Be, Garrett, Gabe), MiddleName(T,R,NAN), LastName(Miller, Vargas, Mares) 

here is the text form of the data frame.

Comment: The reason you are getting "df is not defined" is that you are not loading your dataframe before you call the function.  So you are passing a variable to your function that does not exist yet.  You should move the `pd.read_excel` call outside of the function.  Or remove `df` as a parameter.

Comment: Why does `getFullName()` have a `df` parameter if it is not being used?  [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some fake data for this:

```
           EmployeeID FirstName LastName MiddleName
0          0         a        a          a
1          1         b        b          b
2          2         c        c          c
3          3         d        d          d
4          4         e        e          e
5          5         f        f          f
6          6         g        g          g
7          7         h        h          h
8          8         i        i          i
9          9         j        j       None
```

`EmployeeID` 9 has no middle name, but everyone else does.  The way I would do it is to break up the logic into two parts.  The first, for when you cannot find the `EmployeeID`.  The second manages the printing of the employee's name.  That second part should also have two sets of logic, one to control if the employee has a middle name, and the other for if they don't.  You could likely combine a lot of this into single line statements, but you will likely sacrifice clarity.

I also removed the `pd.read_excel` call from the function.  If you want to pass the dataframe in to the function, then the dataframe should be created oustide of it.

```
def getFullName(df, int1):
   newdf = df[(df['EmployeeID'] == int1)]

   # if the dataframe is empty, then we can't find the give ID
   # otherwise, go ahead and print out the employee's info
   if(newdf.empty):
       print("UNKNOWN")
       return "UNKNOWN"
   else:
       # all strings will start with the LastName and FirstName
       # we will then add the MiddleName if it's present
       # and then we can end the string with the final '
       s = "'" + newdf['LastName'].item() + ", " +newdf['FirstName'].item()
       if (newdf['MiddleName'].item()):
           s = s + " " + newdf['MiddleName'].item() + "."
       s = s + "'"
       print(s)
       return s
```

I have the function returning values in case you want to manipulate the string further.  But that was just me.

If you run `getFullName(df, 1)` you should get `'b, b b.'`.  And for `getFullName(df, 9)` you should get `'j, j'`.

So in full, it would be:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/home/data/AdventureWorks/Employees.xls')
getFullName(df, 1)  #outputs 'b, b b.'
getFullName(df, 9)  #outputs 'j, j'
getFullName(df, 10) #outputs UNKNOWN
```

---

Fake data:

```
d = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
     'FirstName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
     'LastName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
     'MiddleName' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: It might be useful for the OP to see how to create fake data - they requested as much in the question.

Comment: Good call out.  I think OP edited the question after I started answering.

Comment: what does OP stand for?? im sorry guys. Im kinda new to this. and thanks alot for your help. I wish I can help others out in the near future.

Comment: Original Poster

Comment: I am having this error follow for the one does not have a middlename :coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found

Comment: It shouldn't.  I've seen that error before and I don't remember from where. Which line is causing the error?  It sounds like you have a value somewhere that is a float but you are trying to make it a string.

Comment: I am getting the error from                                                                              if (newdf['MiddleName'].item()):
     s = s + " " + newdf['MiddleName'].item() + "."    here, I checked the code with the argument that getting me the error without this line of code and did not give me any error. so this lines should be the problem.

Comment: Does your 'MiddleName' column have floating point values in it?  For example 123.456?

Comment: it has NaN but not floats as far as I know

Comment: NaN is a float and it behaves differently than None.  You can do `df['MiddleName'] = df['MiddleName'].fillna('')`.  That will replace all NaN values with ''.  You can do that right after you load the dataframe from the excel sheet.